# Как получать СМС-код стороннего сервиса и использовать этот код для автотестов?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui, pytest

Товарищи, подскажите. может у кого был опыт:

Есть **UI автотест на Python PyTest и Selenium**, который открывает страницу в браузере, находит кнопку авторизации, заполняет форму и отправляет данные.
После чего, номер телефона отправляется на сторонний сервис, который его обрабатывает и возвращает пользователю смс с кодом, для дальнейшей авторизации на портале.

**Вопрос в следующем, как минуя телефон, получить данный код и подставить его в автотест, для продолжения процесса авторизации?**

*Читал про какой то сторонний сервис рассылки смс (но не совсем понял, как он работает).
Так-же есть мысль, что код который приходит пользователю, должен также дублироваться в сам битрикс, для сравнения отправленного и полученного ключа (но опять же, не пойму, как все это дело подставить в автотест).*

Буду признателен за любую помощь.

Comment: 1) использовать в тестовой среде mock, который генерирует заранее известный код. 2) использовать в тестовой среде mock, который доставляет нужный код до теста не через смс, а каким-то доступным в вашем случае способом. 3) использовать реальные смс и сервис для авторегистрации, который предоставляет номера телефонов и АПИ для получения сообщений по ним. 4) создать самому подобный сервис с автоматизацией принятия смс сообщений 5) Каким-то другим способом получить сгенерированный код

Comment: (6) получать SMS на VoIP телефон, без физического телефона, но с официально существующим номером.